# How do i connect to a remote database in iOS?

Tags: objective-c

Am trying to make a common database for most mobile platforms. The mobile phones will be accessing the db remotely from the application

Answer (score 0):

you would have to make a webservice to do the communicating with the remote db on behalf of the various platforms.

The problem with doing this is you will use a lot of data if the device is doing all its calls to a remote db rather than a local one.

Comment: Webservice like a php script?

Comment: No like an actual webservice hosted in IIS on a server, your IOS app will post requests to the service, which then does all the heavy lifting to the database and it will then return the result to your IOS app.  For example, an asmx webservice, will provide you the remote access regardless of which platform calls it.